# ValueError: base_distribution needs to have shape with size at least 6, but got torch.Size([6])

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have the following architecture for my neural network

```
import torch
import torch.distributions as pyd
import toch.nn as nn
from torch.distributions import transforms as tT
from torch.distributions.transformed_distribution import TransformedDistribution
 
LOG_STD_MIN = -5
LOG_STD_MAX = 0
class TanhTransform(pyd.transforms.Transform):
    domain = pyd.constraints.real
    codomain = pyd.constraints.interval(-1.0, 1.0)
    bijective = True
    sign = +1

    def __init__(self, cache_size=1):
        self.device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        super().__init__(cache_size=cache_size)

    @staticmethod
    def atanh(x):
        return 0.5 * (x.log1p() - (-x).log1p())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, TanhTransform)

    def _call(self, x):
        return x.tanh()

    def _inverse(self, y):
        return self.atanh(y.clamp(-0.99, 0.99))

    def log_abs_det_jacobian(self, x, y):
        return 2.0 * (math.log(2.0) - x - F.softplus(-2.0 * x))

def get_spec_means_mags(spec):
  means = (spec.maximum + spec.minimum) / 2.0
  mags = (spec.maximum - spec.minimum) / 2.0
  means = Variable(torch.tensor(means).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad=False)
  mags  = Variable(torch.tensor(mags).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad=False)
  return means, mags

class Split(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, module, n_parts: int, dim=1):
        super().__init__()
        self._n_parts = n_parts
        self._dim = dim
        self._module = module

    def forward(self, inputs):
        output = self._module(inputs)
        if output.ndim==1:
           result=torch.hsplit(output, self._n_parts )
        else:
           chunk_size = output.shape[self._dim] // self._n_parts
           result =torch.split(output, chunk_size, dim=self._dim)

        return result

class Network(nn.Module):
  def __init__(
      self,
      state,
      act,
      fc_layer_params=(),
      ):
    super(Network, self).__init__()
    self._act = act
    self._layers = nn.ModuleList()
    for hidden_size in fc_layer_params:
        if len(self._layers)==0:
           self._layers.append(nn.Linear(state.shape[0], hidden_size))
        else:
           self._layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size))
        self._layers.append(nn.ReLU())
    output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size,self._act.shape[0] * 2)
    self._layers.append(output_layer)
    
    self._act_means, self._act_mags = get_spec_means_mags(
        self._act)


  def _get_outputs(self, state):
      h = state
      
      for l in nn.Sequential(*(list(self._layers.children())[:-1])):
          h = l(h)

      self._mean_logvar_layers = Split(
         self._layers[-1],
         n_parts=2,
      )
      mean, log_std = self._mean_logvar_layers(h)
      
      a_tanh_mode = torch.tanh(mean) * self._action_mags + self._action_means
      log_std = torch.tanh(log_std).to(device=self.device)
      log_std = LOG_STD_MIN + 0.5 * (LOG_STD_MAX - LOG_STD_MIN) * (log_std + 1)
      std = torch.exp(log_std)
      a_distribution = TransformedDistribution(
                        base_distribution=Normal(loc=torch.full_like(mean, 0).to(device=self.device), 
                                                 scale=torch.full_like(mean, 1).to(device=self.device)), 
                        transforms=tT.ComposeTransform([
                                   tT.AffineTransform(loc=self._action_means, scale=self._action_mags, event_dim=mean.shape[-1]), 
                                   TanhTransform(),
                                   tT.AffineTransform(loc=mean, scale=std, event_dim=mean.shape[-1])]))
      
      return a_distribution, a_tanh_mode

  def get_log_density(self, state, action):
    a_dist, _ = self._get_outputs(state)
    log_density = a_dist.log_prob(action)
    return log_density
  def __call__(self, state):
    a_dist, a_tanh_mode = self._get_outputs(state)
    a_sample = a_dist.sample()
    log_pi_a = a_dist.log_prob(a_sample)
    return a_tanh_mode, a_sample, log_pi_a
```

When I run my code I get this error message:

```
    action = self._a_network(latent_states)[1]
  File "/home/planner_regularizer.py", line 182, in __call__
    a_dist, a_tanh_mode = self._get_outputs(state.to(device=self.device))
  File "/home/planner_regularizer.py", line 159, in _get_outputs
    a_distribution = TransformedDistribution(
  File "/home/dm_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributions/transformed_distribution.py", line 61, in __init__
    raise ValueError("base_distribution needs to have shape with size at least {}, but got {}."
ValueError: base_distribution needs to have shape with size at least 6, but got torch.Size([6]).
```

How can I fix this error message?

**Update**: if I remove `event_dim` from `AffineTransform`, I wouldn't get above error but the output of `log_prob` would be size 1 which is not correct. Any suggestion?

Comment: It might be helpful to add a couple lines where you construct a `Network` instance with representative `state`, `act`, and `fc_layer_params` and then call it, so that your code snippet can be directly executed as a script to reproduce the exception (for this there's also a couple missing imports and a discrepancy between `self._act_*` in the constructor vs `self._action_*` in `_get_outputs`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: TransformedDistribution expects the base distribution to have event_shape of at least length 6, but you are passing a Normal distribution with event_shape=[6].
This minimum length requirement exists because TransformedDistribution applies affine transforms, which require at least 2 dimensions:

1 for the batch_shape
1 for the event coordinates being transformed

Simply construct your Normal distribution with more dimensions, e.g.
Normal(loc=torch.zeros(1, 6), scale=torch.ones(1, 6))